# SQL max product price

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, max

I have a table of products and each record has the price it was sold at, which can vary

```
Product          Price
a                2
a                3
a                4
a                1
b                10
b                15
b                20
```

I want a query which will give be the max price at which product a was sold and max price at which product b was sold and nothing more

I have thousands of products so case will not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MAX` and `Group By`

```
SELECT Product, MAX(Price)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Product
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select product, max(price) as max_price
from products
group by product
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` function and `Group By` keyword

```
SELECT Product, MAX(Price) FROM products  GROUP BY Product
```